# "UnfinishedStubbingException: Unfinished stubbing detected here" has been thrown when mocking static void method

Tags: java, testing, exception, mockito, powermockito

I am getting the error message Unfinished Stubbing detected here, when running the following code:

This is the MyClass with public static void myMethod.

```
class MyClass{
public static void myMethod(){
    return;
}
```

}

This is MyClass2 with myMethod2 mehtod. Inside myMethod2, myMethod is calling.

```
class MyClass2{
public String myMethod2(){
    MyClass.myMethod();
    return "String";
}
```

}

Here the test case written to test myMethod2.

```
class MyMethodTest{
MyClass2 myClass2;
@Test
public void myMethodTwoTest(){
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(MyClass.class);
    MyClass.myMethod();
    String str = myClass2.myMethod2();
    assertEquals(str,"String");
}
```

}

When running this method I am getting UnfinishedStubbingException.

````
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at **.***.***.**.MyMethodTest.myMethodTwoTest(MyMethodTest.java:125)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();```


Please help me to solve this issue.
````

Comment: These developers are nuts

Answer (score 0):

I believe https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods gives a good explanation. Looking at that I think something like the following should work:

```
class MyMethodTest{
MyClass2 myClass2;
@Test
public void myMethodTwoTest(){
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class).when(MyClass::myMethod).doNothing();
    String str = myClass2.myMethod2();
    assertEquals(str,"String");
}
```